# Initializing IB Controls Programmatically in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I have a simple app and I want to load initial settings for the UI elements. But I don't want to have to IBOutlet each one of them. Is there a way to address them programmatically and set their values. for example:

```
if (user hasn't created a default){
   // load the default settings
   button1 = 12;
   label.text = text;
   etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UIButtons is

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(signatureOfYourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 3):

The entire purpose of `IBOutlet` is so that you can set and get their values programmatically, so I don't quite understand why you wouldn't use `IBOutlet`. Usually when you create in Interface Builder you use IBOutlets for anything you need to interact with programmatically. (Obviously, when create them programmatically, you don't need an IBOutlet.)

But if you *really* want to add the controls in Interface Builder and not use IBOutlets, you could set the numeric `tag` property with some unique value in the attributes inspector under the "view" settings. You can then programmatically retrieve the reference for that from your view controller as `[self.view viewWithTag:tagNumber];`. This is more awkward and less efficient, so I'd really encourage you to use `IBOutlet`. Is there some compelling reason not to?